# Why does Chrome user agent string change in windows 8?

Tags: php, google-chrome, browser-detection

In my computer with windows 8 and Google Chrome 35, the variable $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] sometimes returns

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.4; en-us; Kindle Fire HD Build/GINGERBREAD) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
```

when the correct value would be:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36
```

Why does it happen and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Whats the value of navigator.userAgent in the JavaScript console in Chrome ? Can you mention the scenarios in which it happens sometimes. Also if you are checking the user agent of a request from a server its possible that the user agent is the actual user agent of the device which has made the request.

Comment: I wonder hadn't one tried the emulation mode (of Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

[**Kindle**](https://www.google.com/search?q=kindle+download) is both a hardware e-reader and a piece of software to read e-books on computers, laptops and tablets. Could it be that you installed that on your machine and that it nested itself in Chrome, like a plug-in/add-on?

If you're sure no such thing is the case, consider the suggestion by Alok in the comments. If you wouldn't know how to work with the console, [**check here**](http://conijnwebdesign.nl/tutorials/client-conf.php) whether the PHP- and JS-detected uAs read the same. If not, that would indeed be the cause.

Although I wouldn't know how to cure that then, other than by removing the (other) plug-ins/add-ons one by one.